Display standard numeric format with units
I am using ejs-numerictextbox and want to use the locale specific number format but with a unit suffix, e.g. 1,000 kg.
The format 'N' displays the number as I'd like, but adding a unit on the end breaks the format, e.g. 'N kg' isn't valid.
I can do '#,###,###,###,###,###,###,###.######################## kg' but this is rather clunky and I want it to use different thousand separators / decimal based on the locale.
Also, in the unlikely event that the user enters very large numbers / lots of decimals, it won't work properly.
Is there a better way of doing this?
In case it matters I'm using the Syncfusion libraries in a Vue component.
